# Google Sheets text rotated up, how to clip text end instead of beginning?

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-cell-format

I have a very large table where the columns and rows are named, and interior cells are "1" or empty (essentially a sparse matrix). I have rotated the column header text direction up so that the columns may be narrow. Here is a simplified example:

[image: Table, column names "alpha bravo charlie delta" and "short item", row names "red", "green", and "blue". Internal values 1, blank, 1, blank, blank, 1.]

Some column names are very long, so the cells cannot be the entire height of the column names. When I resize the column name row to be smaller height, the text is clipped in the wrong direction. Prefixes of the names are incorrectly cut off instead of suffixes as desired. **See cell B1** in simplified example of the problem:

[image: Same table, column header row resized to small height. Column header names have prefix clipped instad of suffix.]

*How can I change the direction that text clipping occurs?*

Comment: Have you tried changing "Text Wrapping" -> "Wrap"?

Comment: There is no solution at the time being for your question. Best thing to do would be to submit a feature request by using Google Feedback found on the top menu under `Help`-> `Report a problem`.

Comment: Thanks, I have submitted a feature request as you described.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For now, I have worked around the issue by rotating the text down instead of up. Although this doesn't achieve the alignment aesthetic I wanted, it will suffice for now, and clipping end of value text works properly.

[image: Same table, column headers have text rotated down instead of up. Long column header value text displays the beginning of value and clips the of value, as desired.]

Answer (score 3):

You have a long header cell that you have rotated to save space. However, when the height of the row is shortened, a "long" value is effectively right-aligned so that the end of the value is shown rather than the beginning.

As noted by @marikamitsos, it's not possible to do what you wish.

However, wrapping the text is a good work-around to display the entire cell while keeping a relatively narrow column width.

---

[image]

Comment: Thanks for your response.